# PHP HTML multiple id of form into modal body

Tags: php, html, modal-dialog

I have a table showing the summary for every ticket submitted from user.
Every line of this table has a "Charge Exp" button, that opens a modal that allows to load the expenses for every ticket opened from the user.

[image]

```
<table id="ticketList" class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
      <!-- header fields -->
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php
      if($numrows_ticket > 0 ) {
        if($numrows_ticket < $limit){
          $limit = $numrows_ticket;
        }
        for($i = $paginationStart; $i < ($paginationStart+$limit);$i++){
        ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $arr[$i]['jira_id'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $arr[$i]['project'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo date_format(date_create($arr[$i]['data']), "d/m/y H:i");?></td>
        <td><?php echo $arr[$i]['id_user'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo "xXstatusXx";?></td>
        <td><button id="btnExp" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#chargeExpenses"><?php echo "Charge Exp"?></button>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal" id="chargeExpenses" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="expensesForm" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header"></div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <?php include "load_expenses.php";?>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

When I write the data into the fields of the modal (without submitting), the same content appears if I close, go to a different line and open a new modal. When I submit, multiple forms for every line of the table are submitted.

**load_expenses.php:**

```
<?php error_log("counter load exp: ".$i);?>
<form action="xxx.php" method="post" id="exp_form-<?php echo $i?>" class="spellcheck exclusive save" name="dett2-<?php echo $i?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

In the log I have $i from 0 to 9, as I'd expect. The id and name of the form is however always 0.

What's wrong and what could be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have only one modal and whenever you add something to it it stays there just gets hide when you close the modal .
There can be some options to do it one of them can be that you use modal id different for each modal  like

```
 <div class="modal" id="chargeExpenses[$x]" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="expensesForm" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header"></div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <?php include "load_expenses.php";?>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

and when you open up the modal just pass the id of the row you clicked

Comment: It worked :D I created different id for every modal and of course replaced the button data target to match it